# Mongodb aggregation pipeline algorithm performance

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, aggregation-framework

Is there any documentation that talks about MongoDb aggregation pipeline operators' algorithm performance. For example: If I do a $merge involving 5 records and the same done on 500 records, what is the order of the algorithm? O(1) or O(n). Similarly, I would like know know what each operator is depdendent on. Please help

Comment: What about profiling it with different sizes of n?

Comment: MongoDB is a rather new software, I don't think you can get such detailed information. So time ago I created a ticket regarding performance https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53503 - no reply so far.

Comment: This article might help you with aggregation pipeline Optimization. 
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/